# pass the values as a parameter to the ng click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello take a look at sample code which is bind in html using ng-bind html directive.

```
var _test = new Object();
<div ng-click="myFunc()"></div>
```

I am able to get click successfully also. If we pass simple string as

```
var _test = "1111";
```

Then on click of this div i am able to get this values.

Is there any way to pass the object to myFunc?

Comment: What stopping you from doing that?

Comment: it is giving me error.

Comment: i dnt know whether i am following the right approach or not

Comment: It would be very helpful to know *which* error, don't you think?

Comment: Error: Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 16 of the expression [myFunc([object Object])] starting at [Object])].

Answer (score 1):

```
// create an object on your scope
$scope.myObj = {};

// pass it in in your markup
<div ng-click="myFunc(myObj)"></div>
```